# equals string в циклах java

Tags: java

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stroka2;
        do{
            System.out.println("Опять тесты, играем? y/n?");
            String stroka = scn.next();
            if (stroka.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Теперь введите какое нибудь число, которое будет чуть больше 110ти");
                int chislo = scn.nextInt();
                if (chislo > 110) {
                    System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                    String stroka2 = scn.next();
                    if(!stroka2.equals("Андрей")){
                        System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + stroka2 + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ты тупой или че? Еще раз пытайся");
                    int chislo2 = scn.nextInt();
                    if (chislo2 > 110) {
                        System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                        String stroka2 = scn.next();
                        if(!stroka2.equals("Андрей")) {
                            System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + stroka2 + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Может все таки сделаешь о чем я прошу?????");
                        int chislo3 = scn.nextInt();
                        if (chislo3 > 110) {
                            System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                            String stroka2 = scn.next();
                            if(!stroka2.equals("Андрей")) {
                                System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + stroka2 + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if(stroka.equals("n")){
                System.out.println("Хорошего дня!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("у тебя два варианта");
            }
        }while(stroka2.equals("Андрей"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть такой код, проблема в самой последней строчке. stroka2,stroka3.stroka4 подсвечены красным и идея пишет cannot resolve symbol. Пробовал просто цикл while без do, результат тот же, while будто не видит строки введенные пользователем. что делаю не так?

Comment: Проблема в непонимании областей видимости. Вы обращаетесь к переменным, которые ещё не объявлены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, вот ответ.

```
public static void main(String arr[]){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userAnswer;
        int userNumber;
        do{
            System.out.println("Опять тесты, играем? y/n?");
            userAnswer = scn.nextLine(); 
            if (userAnswer.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Теперь введите какое нибудь число, которое будет чуть больше 110ти");
                userNumber = scn.nextInt();
                if (userNumber > 110) {
                    System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                    userAnswer = scn.nextLine();
                    if(!userAnswer.equals("Андрей")){
                        System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + userAnswer + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ты тупой или че? Еще раз пытайся");
                    userNumber = scn.nextInt();
                    if (userNumber > 110) {
                        System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                        userAnswer = scn.nextLine();
                        if(!userAnswer.equals("Андрей")) {
                            System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + userAnswer + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Может все таки сделаешь о чем я прошу?????");
                        int chislo3 = scn.nextInt();
                        if (chislo3 > 110) {
                            System.out.println("ты молодец, теперь введи свое имя, имей ввиду если ты Андрей то у тебя проблемы");
                            userAnswer = scn.nextLine();
                            if(!userAnswer.equals("Андрей")) {
                                System.out.println("Приятно познакомиться " + userAnswer + ", а меня зовут Жора");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if(userAnswer.equals("n")){
                System.out.println("Хорошего дня!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("у тебя два варианта");
            }


        }while(userAnswer.equals("Андрей"));
    }
```

Comment: Я также сделал когда вы мне написали о том что ссылаюсь на переменную которая еще не объявлена. Теперь userNumber внутри цикла подчеркнут красным и идея пишет что "is already defined in the scope"

Comment: @jewbaka внимательно сравните ваш код с кодом в ответе.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это сложно назвать кодом

Comment: @raviga согласен. Я сделал ему медвежью услугу

Answer (score 0):

Код не запускал, но одно сказать точно могу. Ты можешь ответить нет. Вот незадача - строк stroka2, stroka3,stroka4 не существует в природе, так как ты их создаешь только при утвердительном ответе. Ты ссылаешься на поля, которых в памяти нет. Советую их объявить перед циклом do-while, либо в самом его начале перед началом "логики".

И да - ты мог использовать лишь одну переменную(из тех, где могут быть "Андреи"). Внимательно посмотри на ветку. Ты в любом случае вводишь лишь одну переменную. Зачем тебе целых три?

Comment: Error:(17, 28) java: variable stroka2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
Error:(28, 32) java: variable stroka3 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
Error:(38, 36) java: variable stroka4 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: можешь код обновить(в вопросе)?